# blender Sculptmode alt + "leftclick" dosent work

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, keymap

I was searching for many solutions. While im in Sculpt mode I cant change the object with alt + "leftclick". I even tried shift + alt + "leftclick" and shift + ctrl + a "leftclick".

annyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut to change object is now <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!